# Calculate $f(0), f(1)$ of a function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5x^n}{3^n(1-2x)}$ and assume this function is defined wherever this series converges. Calculate $f(0)$, $f(1)$, and determine whether $f(x) \leq 0$ for all x in the domain. For $f(0)$ this seems to be trivial as it evaluates to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0$, which is just 0. For $f(1)$, it seems like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{-3^n}$, which I would have to calculate what it converges to. I ended up with $f(1)=\frac{-5}{2}$. Is this correct?

For the last question, whether $f(x) \leq 0$ or not, I hypothesize that it is. I used multiple other values such as $f(2)$, $f(2.5)$, etc. (Also I didn't use values outside of the domain.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your answers to the first part by evaluating $f(x)$ in closed form, something that will in any case help greatly with the second part:

$$\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{5x^n}{3^n(1-2x)}\\
&=\frac5{1-2x}\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{x}3\right)^n\\
&=\frac5{1-2x}\cdot\frac{\frac{x}3}{1-\frac{x}3}\\
&=\frac{5x}{(1-2x)(3-x)}
\end{align*}$$

for $|x|<3$, provided that $x\ne\frac12$. Thus, $f(0)=0$, and $f(1)=\frac5{(-1)(2)}=-\frac52$.

The second question is then whether $f(x)\le 0$ for all $$x\in\left(-3,\frac12\right)\cup\left(\frac12,3\right)\,,$$ the domain of $f$, and that’s a straightforward algebra problem. First, $3-x>0$ for all $x\in(-3,3)$, so the sign of $f(x)$ is the same as the sign of $\frac{x}{1-2x}$. What happens of $0<x<\frac12$?

Comment: Woah! the God of Math just answered my question!? For the second question I think $\frac{x}{1-2x}$ stays positive in the range $0 <x<\frac{1}{2}$, which would mean that the sign of $f(x)$ is positive?

Comment: @ATMOS-atms: That’s right!